# POST request with nested JSON parameters malformed in request.POST

Tags: python, json, django, post, pytest

Inside integration tests, I try to make a POST request with a nested JSON parameter (this is just one of the approaches I tried):

```
test_function(admin_client):
    admin_client.post(some_url,
                      json.dumps(some_nested_json),
                      content_type='application/json',
                      headers={'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'})
```

I've also tried all sorts of different combinations for the parameters etc., everything I could find on the web, but I can't get the proper JSON output in the received `request.JSON`.

I get one of these three cases:

- `request.POST` contains the first level of JSON plus the arrays of second level JSON *keys*
- `request.POST` contains the first level of JSON plus an empty second level JSON
- `request.POST` is empty, but `request.body` contains the whole nested JSON, in expected format

What am I missing here? I'm using *Python 2.7*.

Comment: Just by the way: Stop using 2.7, it is going to be discontinued past 1.1.2020. https://pythonclock.org

Comment: Legacy code reasons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior in django. Json requests are not in in `request.POST` but in `request.body`. You need to manually do `json.loads(request.body)` in your view.

Comment: The existing code does a nested JSON object lookup on the `request.POST`, so ti has to work somehow...

Comment: removing headers in post request would put data in `request.POST`

Comment: Yes, but this would create the first case I mentioned.

Comment: OK, so the problem was that the data was sent as a JSON but in a string format. Since your answer (and @Crystal's) is correct, I'll accept it.